# How to export the current Process Template (TFS 2015 update 3)

Tags: tfs-2015

We had an outside vendor modify the CMMI process template. They created a new version XXX_CMMI.

Over the last few weeks we have been adding fields to a few of the WITS (requirement and bug). For the interim I have just been using witadmin to update the existing projects.
I exported the update wit as a file and saved it to my workstation.
Then I just wrote a batch file the used witadmin to upload the wit to each project.

What I want to do is update the XXX_CMMI process template with the changes.

So that any new projects that use the XXX_CMMI template get those updates too.
What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Once you've created a Team Project, **you unfortunately can't just upload a new process template.**

There has been a uservoice and getting started now:

> [Allow for updating process templates on existing projects in TFS](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/2105201-allow-for-updating-process-templates-on-existing-p)
>
> **STARTED  ·**   *Visual Studio Team ADMIN Visual Studio Team (Product
>   Team, Microsoft Visual Studio) responded  ·  Jan 27, 2016*

For now, you have to download the XML for the template and modify it, then re-upload it. The power tool lets you create **NEW templates** for N**EW team projects**, but it won't modify an existing one.

Instead, you can use the `witadmin.exe` tool to export the current workitem definitions and re-import them once you've made your changes.

If you're not using workitem tracking much, then this might not be too difficult. You might be able to just delete all the existing workitem types and then re-upload the new types.

If this is too much trouble, consider how much you want to retain your source control history. You can also create a new Team Project with the template and then just moving all your source code into it.

---

For more other ways, it's also worth looking at this blog: [Upgrading your Process Template in Team Foundation Server](https://nkdagility.com/do-you-know-how-to-upgrade-a-process-template-but-still-keep-your-data-intact/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this powershell script](https://github.com/Microsoft/process-customization-scripts) to achieve this feature. Refer to this link for details: [Scripts to import and export process templates from TFS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/02/03/scripts-to-import-and-export-process-templates-from-tfs/).